# Markov chain text generation in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, natural-language-processing, markov-chain

I'm willing to listen to any advice you have for improving it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

import nltk
import numpy as np

seq, freq, sample = [t for ts in [[None] + nltk.casual_tokenize(line) + [None] for line in open("file.txt").readlines()] for t in ts], defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)), lambda curr: np.random.choice(list(freq[curr].keys()), p=[x/sum(freq[curr].values()) for x in freq[curr].values()])
for a, b in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:]): freq[a][b] += 0 if a is None and b is None else 1
curr = sample(None)
while curr != None: _, curr = print(curr, end=" "), sample(curr)
```

Answer (score 6):

Holy incomprehensible comprehensions!

There is no good justification for defining `seq`, `freq`, and `sample` all as one statement.  Each of them is already complex enough on its own.

There is also no good reason to write your last `while` loop as a one-liner.

With just those changes and some indentation…

```
from collections import defaultdict

import nltk
import numpy as np

seq = [
    t for ts in [
        [None] + nltk.casual_tokenize(line) + [None]
        for line in open("file.txt").readlines()
    ]
    for t in ts
]
freq = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
sample = lambda curr: np.random.choice(
    list(freq[curr].keys()),
    p=[x / sum(freq[curr].values()) for x in freq[curr].values()]
)
for a, b in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:]):
    freq[a][b] += 0 if a is None and b is None else 1
curr = sample(None)
while curr != None:
    print(curr, end=" ")
    curr = sample(curr)
```

… we might start to hope to understand the code.

---

What's `[t for ts in [[…]] for t in ts]`?  It's just flattening a list of lists.  I'd write that as `list(itertools.chain(*[[…]]))`.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    seq = list(itertools.chain(*[
        [None] + nltk.casual_tokenize(line) + [None]
        for line in f
    ]))
```

However, once you flatten it, you get `…, None, None, …` as placeholders for the linebreaks.  You later have to do extra work to filter out `if a is None and b is None` when constructing the `freq` matrix.  So why even bother creating `seq` as a flattened list in the first place, if all you want is a frequency matrix?

```
from collections import Counter

def frequency_table(file):
    freq = defaultdict(Counter)
    for line in file:
        tokens = nltk.casual_tokenize(line)
        for a, b in zip(tokens + [None], [None] + tokens):
            freq[a][b] += 1
    return freq
```

`sample` would be clearer if written as a function.  I'd make it take a `freq` parameter instead of using `freq` as a global.

```
def sample(freq, curr):
    return np.random.choice(
        list(freq[curr].keys()),
        p=[x / sum(freq[curr].values()) for x in freq[curr].values()]
    )
```

I don't know if performance is an issue here, but you might be better off normalizing the probabilities instead of recalculating `[x / sum(freq[curr].values()) for x in freq[curr].values()]` with each call to `sample()`.

It would be nice to convert your final loop into a generator:

```
def markov_chain(freq, word=None):
    while True:
        word = sample(freq, word)
        if word is None:
            break
        yield word
```

With those three function definitions in place, the rest of the code looks pretty straightforward:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    freq = frequency_table(f)
for word in markov_chain(freq):
    print(word, end=" ")
```